# An asymmetrical distribution with mode at 0?

Tags: distributions, skewness

I am modelling some process where I logically want the residuals to have a maximum probability of being zero, but with more 'tolerance' towards positive residuals. So I'm looking for a distribution which has the following properties:

- asymmetrical
- a mode at zero
- covers negative and positive values

Precisely, I'm trying to model a population recruitment process over time. Recruitment is varies around a mean, but in some years peaks are known to occur, which I would like to account for.

In case this does simply not exist, is there another way of dealing properly with this? For example, adding the distribution's mode x-value to the residuals, so they're shifted (would this be allowed)?

Comment: Once a distribution is asymmetric, it's no longer clear what is meant by "centered". Do you take to that be mean zero?

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks. I mean that the 'peak' value should be around at zero.

Comment: You want the *mode* to be zero? So you would say that a chisquare(2) already had its center at 0?

Comment: I don't think this is a difficult technicality. A symmetric distribution has a centre, which is defined by an axis of symmetry. If you want to use the word centre in a wider sense, you have to give a definition, and (as @Glen_b is commenting) mode would be a surprising choice.

Comment: Yes. But a chisquare(2) doesn't allow for negative values. I'll adapt my word choice in the question.

Comment: Your choice of distribution should reflect the properties of the process.  Unless you share some information about it with us, we cannot do much more than guess and speculate.

Comment: Take any higher d.f. $k$ of the $\chi^2$ and shift it by $k-2$, the mode?

Comment: I also added a basic explanation of the process. I like the idea of Christoph Hanck, and I'll give this a try. Though I am surprised that there is no distribution that fits these needs. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Well, the one I gave *is* a distribution, it may just not carry a well-known name (call it "shifted $\chi^2$"). Any asymmetric distribution could be shifted that way, think of, e.g., $F$, Gamma, log-normal or Beta.